# Variable loses data when I run another App

Tags: android

I built a variable to work as a Session. I am saving the ID from specific users on log in.

I am declaring the variable inside my Sign In asynctask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if(result == ""){
        this.statusField.setText("Wrong password.");
    }else{

        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ListUsersActivity.class));

       Session.suserid = result;
    }
}

public static class Session{
    public static String suserid; 
}
```

My session class:

```
public class NewSession extends Application {

   Session session = new Session();

   public String getUserId() {
      return session.suserid;
   }
}
```

To get the ID from the user, I just need to call it:

```
 NewSession app = (NewSession) getApplication();
 userid = app.getUserId();
```

The code is working fine, but when I run Google Chrome, YouTube, or a different application, when I try to run my application again, it gives me an error because my Session loses the value.

Is there any similar way to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: When you leave the app, the system may decide to end the process and free up memory. What lifecycle events does it go through when you leave the app and return? Look into saving state in onPause() or onStop() and loading it in onResume() or onStart()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code is working fine, but when I run Google Chrome, YouTube, or a different application, when I try to run my application again, it gives me an error because my Session loses the value.

Your process was terminated due to low memory conditions. This is [perfectly normal](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

Static data members, including custom `Application` objects, are just a transient cache. If you have data that you want to hang onto, that data needs to be backed by a persistent data store: database, `SharedPreferences`, some other form of file, the Internet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the OnPause and OnResume events in your Session activity to save and restore the data from the savedInstanceState bundle.